# How to configure macOS Network settings per connection

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

I'm using macbook air with Mavericks. I'm connecting so many wireless network, I could set up TCP/IP settings per network which I connected. How can I do this in Mavericks?

example: I have a router in my home and I want connect this router with manual TCP/IP settings like ip, dns, etc. and I have a router in my office too, but I want connect this router with DHCP. In Linux OSes, network settings setting per network. I'm using Mac OS X now and How can I do that in Mavericks?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.  Question does not contain remotely enough information on your problem and what you are trying to achieve.  Broadly speaking, network information is handed out by a server/service called DHCP for each network, generally on a router for home and small network setups; larger networks have more sophisticated and therefore complex configurations, but these are usually managed by professional network administrators.

Comment: I give an example: I have a router in my home and I want connect this router with manuel TCP/IP settings like ip, dns, etc. and I have a router in my office too, but I want connect this router with DHCP. In Linux OSes, network settings setting per network. I'm using Mac OS X now and How can I do that in Mavericks?

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen this in linux. network settings are defined by interface, not by network.

Comment: You can set network settings per network in linux. Wireless networks already set per ssid, also you can set network settings for ethernet interface if you create profiles to select when you connected to internet via ethernet interface.

Comment: Please edit your new information into your question.

Comment: Either you have your **network interface** setup with manual, *static settings*, **OR** you have it setup to configure *automatically*.  Automatic configuration is handled by a system called **DHCP**.  Your computer (Operating system actually) can not possibly know what network it is on until it has a network configuration.  DHCP works with your client sending a message to the broadcast address 255.255.255.255, and the server sends back the configuration to 0.0.0.0 paired with your client's MAC (hardware) address.  Your client/computer then says, "oh, that is me, so that will be my config."

Comment: Why you typing everythin except my question's answer? I can do it on Linux! You can search it if you don't know.

Comment: With some home routers , you can configure to hand out a specific config to a specific to a specific MAC address.  How much of the config you can customise depends on the router.  With a full server system, Windows or Linux, you can fully customise the what is handed out to a specific MAC address.

Comment: Maybe if you said exactly what your Linux config was, then we we could  help you with a specific config for your MacOSX.  Right now, your details are incomplete.

Comment: I'm not using Linux anymore, but anybody still understand my problem, I will install on vm and can take screenshots.

Comment: Please think through what you are asking:  You are asking to you have your computer automatically decide to be either in DHCP mode, or in Static Mode, depending on what network your computer is attached to.  Please answer me this: How does  your computer know which network it is attached into: your home network, your work network, or some other random network?  Could you provide a link to a google search for this linux config that you are talking about?

Comment: Linux can do it. In wireless, configures saved by SSID; in ethernet, it doesn't save but you can create profile for eth interface and ypu can select profile after plugged ethernet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The feature you are asking for is called [Locations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202480), found in System Preferences > Network > Location pop-up menu.

#### Example

[image: ss#1]

**NOTE:** Once you have created and set additional network locations, you can then use the Location menu item from the Apple menu to switch to a different location.

#### References

- http://www.cultofmac.com/242667/add-network-locations-and-switch-among-them-in-the-apple-menu-os-x-tips/
- http://macs.about.com/od/networking/qt/networklocation.htm